# How to add servicemonitor for pgbouncer-exporter metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, pgbouncer, servicemonitor

I have added `pgbouncer-exporter` container to my deployment. It is emitting the metrics on port `9100`.
I want to add a scraper for these metrics so that it becomes visible in Prometheus.
How can I do it by using Kubernetes `ServiceMonitor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with [`pgbouncer-exporter`](https://github.com/prometheus-community/pgbouncer_exporter) but the principles are consistent irrespective of technology.

You'll need to:

1. Ensure the `pgbouncer_exporter`'s port (default `9127`?) is published so that the `/metrics` are accessible beyond the Pod.
2. Test `GET`'ting the endpoint (e.g. `kubectl port-forward` to the `Deployment`) to ensure that `/metrics` is accessible.
3. Determine whether to use a [`ServiceMonitor`](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/design.md#servicemonitor) or [`PodMonitor`](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/design.md#podmonitor). If you have a Service exposing `pgbouncer_exporter`, then use `ServiceMonitor`. Otherwise, use `PodMonitor`
4. Configure `*Monitor`'s `selector` and `port`
5. Apply the config to your cluster in the `Namespace` of your `Deployment`.

Comment: There are actually at least two `prometheus-pgbouncer-exporter` python projects, one is incompatible with the current version of pgbouncer and defaults to port 9127. The other seems to be activately maintained and defaults to port 9100. There might be more.